# Are simultaneous reads from an array thread-safe?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have an array which contains integer values declared like this:

```
int data[] = new int[n];
```

Each value needs to be processed and I am splitting the work into pieces so that it can be processed by separate threads. The array will not be modified during processing.

Can all the processing threads read separate parts of the array concurrently? Or do I have to use a lock?

In other words: is this work order thread-safe?

```
Array is created and filled
Threads are created and started
Thread 0 reads data[0..3]
Thread 1 reads data[4..7]
Thread 2 reads data[8..n]
```

Comment: Any number of threads can read values. Critical sections only matter when writing is involved.

Comment: @Jyro117 or reading! Iterating over a structure should be synchronized.

Comment: If your structure is being treated as immutable, i.e. no writes to the data inside or the structure itself, you do not need to synchronize it. Unless your structure changes when you read from it, but in the case of arrays that never happens.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison how is this question a duplicate of what you have found? This is a different case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading contents of an array (or any other collection, fields of an object, etc.) by multiple threads is thread-safe provided that the data is not modified in the meantime.

If you fill the array with data to process and pass it to different threads for reading, then the data will be properly read and no data race will be possible.

Note that **this will only work if you create the threads after you have filled the array**. If you pass the array for processing to some already existing threads without synchronization, the contents of the array may not be read correctly. In such case the method in which the thread obtains the reference to the array should be synchronized, because a synchronized block forces memory update between threads.

On a side note: using an immutable collection may be a good idea. That way you ensure no modification is even possible. I would sugges using such wrapper. Check the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package, there should be something you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was wandering if the reverse is also possible, that threads can right at the same time.(These threads will never right to the same index)

Comment: @user2342875 you mean write? If you write to different memory locations from different threads, you will never have any certainty whether the memory will be correctly (with the new value) read from different threads if you do not use synchronization. Synchronization also ensures memory synchronization between threads.

Comment: @user2342875 I reworked my answer and mentioned a potential pitfall; take it into account in your code.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the threads don't modify the contents in the array, it is fine to read the array from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure all the threads are just reading, its thread safe. Though you should not  be relying on that fact `alone` and try to make your array immutable via a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you just want to read it, pass the array to the threads when you create them. There won't be any problem as long as you don't **modify** it.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from array array is Thread-Safe Operation but if you are Modifying array than consider using class [**AtomicIntegerArray**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consider populating a [ConcurrendLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and have each thread pull from it. This would ensure that there are no concurrency issues.

Your threads would each be pulling their data from the top of the queue and processing it.